# Dependencies among Typescript projects (within one repo)

Tags: typescript

I have a series of Typescript projects (each an actual compilable target, with its own tsconfig.json). They are sibling directories within one code repository, like this:

```
myrepo
--/common
--/project1
--/project2
```

In order to share code between `project1` and `project2`, I've broken some shared code out into `common`. I would like to allow `project1` and `project2` code to import classes from `common`, but not from each other (and `common` should not be able to import classes from either of the other two).

Ideally, code in `project1` might look like this:

```
import {CommonClass} from 'common/commonclass';
```

I have found a way to allow the importing to work correctly, by putting this into the tsconfig.json of `project1`:

```
  "baseUrl":".",
  "paths":{
    "*":["*","../*"]
  }
```

However, I have not yet found a way to limit which of the other subprojects can be the subject of an `import`. I've tried using `rootDirs`, hoping that it would restrict the allowable source files in the same way `rootDir` does, but it actually does not.

How could I whitelist what code is importable in each of my projects? Or is there just some better way of building subprojects in Typescript that I'm not aware of?

Comment: How are your projects compiled? This is an everyday problem here and I can share my approach.

Comment: Just with `tsickle` (a wrapped drop-in replacement for `tsc`) on the command line, actually via a makefile.

Comment: I mean, what is the typescript output? Compiled into single file, or each file compiled in place?

Comment: Each file compiled independently; tsickle just changes the packaging output to be compatibile with the Closure compiler, which we use to package it up afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I also had to deal with a similar structure and couldn't find an ideal way to do so.
The best I managed to come up with is having a `lib` directory in `project1` and `project2` which contains the compiled `common` alongside the definition files.

I used gulp to build the `common` project into the different `projectX/lib` directories:

```
gulp.task("common-project1", function () {
    var tsProject = ts.createProject("common/tsconfig.json");

    return tsProject.src("common/**/*.ts")
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("project1/lib/common"));
});
```

It's not the best solution because it requires you to run this gulp task every time you change the `common` source, but I'v discovered that it doesn't happen very often once that `common` is stable enough.

Comment: Exactly what I do, although I also use `gulp.watch` (it synergizes well with _Compile on save_), which enables files to be synced across projects almost instantly. The notable side-effect here is the lack of inter-project refactoring. E.g. if you do a global rename on an object (i.e. `Ctrl + R + R` in VS), the change does not propagate beyond the project and its replicated files (although I feel this should not be a problem with well defined APIs and loosely coupled dependencies, where the public signature is only altered occasionally, if ever).

Comment: Right, that is a downside, but if you look at the common more like a 3rd party library then it becomes clear that there are advantages to this approach, especially in the long run. Over time the `common` lib will mature enough so that (1) it's not required to make changes, and (2) if a change is necessary it will affect too many dependent projects to make this change a simple matter.

Comment: I actually tried something similar, but with symlinks instead of copying files, and found out that `tsc` actually noticed that the files were really coming from outside the `rootDir` and gave an error :-(

Comment: Then try copying the js/d.ts files to be under the `rootDir`, it works pretty well

Answer (score 0):

You can use `noResolve` compiler option in the tsconfig.json, please refer to the [Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

For example: in your project2/tsconfig.json, you can set `noResolve` to true, and specify all required paths in `include`

```js
// project2/tsconfig.json

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noResolve": true
    },
    "include": [
        "../common/**/*",
        "**/*"
    ]
}
```

With above settings, TypeScript will warn you about the wrong import of ProjectUtil1:

```js
// project2/ProjectUtil2.ts

import ProjectUtil1 from "../project1/ProjectUtil1";    // TypeScript error
import StringUtil from "../common/StringUtil";

export class ProjectUtil2 {

    static formatOutput(text: string) {
        return "Project 2: " + ProjectUtil1.formatOutput(text);
    }
}

export default ProjectUtil2;
```